# How to solve $x= \sin(k- x)$?

Tags: functions

Is there a way to solve $x = \sin (k-x)$ without a computer, that is with a pocket calculator or pencil and paper?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Draw two curves: $y=x$ and $y=\sin(k-x)$ for a given $k$. See then where these two curves intersect.

Comment: What do you want to solve: $x =\sin x$ or $x = \sin(k-x) $ ? Be specific. Their solution procedure might be similar but solns are different

Comment: Depending on the accuracy needed you could use taylor series.

Comment: Any you want really, the more terms you have from the serie the greater accuracy do you get. Keep in mind however that the polynomial to solve them grows nasty quickly. It can however be combined with the newton-raphne method of finding 0s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Equations which mix polynomial and trigonometric terms do not show analytical solutions (this is already the case of $x=\cos(x)$) and numerical method (such as Newton) should be used.

Let us consider the case of the zero of $$f(x)=x-\sin(k-x)$$ admitting $0 <k <\pi$. We can notice that $f(0)=-\sin(k) <0$ and $f(k)=k>0$. On the other side, since $\sin(\theta)<1$, we can restrict the range between $0$ and $1$.

So, let us use Newton method starting at $x_0=1$. The iterative scheme would be $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n-\sin (k-x_n)}{1+\cos (k-x_n)}$$ Let us use $k=3$ as in your comment; then the successive iterates will be $$x_1=0.844648$$ $$x_2=0.820794$$ $$x_3=0.820243$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Obviously, you can easily do it using a simple pocket calculator.

Comment: I think $f(X)$ is always a contraction map on $R$, so maybe there is a even slicker method with a pocket calculator: just randomly pick some $x_0\in\Bbb R$, then use the iteration $ANS=f(ANS)$. :)

Comment: @vim: the fixed-point approach works very conveniently for the equation $x=\cos(x)$, by typematicly pressing the $\cos$ key (though convergence is slow).

Answer (score 0):

As Oliver and Subhadeep Dey have suggested, drawing the graphs of $y=x$ and  $y=\sin(k-x)$ and finding out their points of intersection will yield the required solutions.

However you could go for the taylor series expansion of $\sin x$ but the resulting equation would be a bit less precise (as per your demands) depending on the approximation you take.

Again, I can think of one method involving pocket calculator.Since $-1\le \sin x\le 1$,so $-1\le  x\le 1$. 
 See, you can locate the roots by considering the function $y=x-\sin(k-x)$ 
 So, $y_1 = f'(x) = 1 + \cos (k-x) \ge 0 \,\ \forall \,\ x\in R$ 
 So $y=f(x)$ is an increasing function and hence it will have only one root. 
 $f(-1)=-[1+\sin (k+1)]\le 0$ and $f(0)=-\sin k$ and $f(1)=1-\sin(k-1) \ge 0 \,\ \text{and} \,\ \in [0,2]$ 
 So depending on your value of $k$, you can get an estimate of which interval your root lies and almost the exact value of the root using your calculator.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to solve the equation for several (many) values of $k$, then it can be attractive to work in reverse: you can express $k$ as a function of $x$ with

$$k=x+\arcsin(x)$$

and easily compute $(x,k)$ pairs.

When switching the values, you get a smooth monotonous curve that can be well approximated by a polynomial. (There is another branch, omitted here.) By symmetry, it is enough to consider the half with $k>0$.

**Plot of $x$ as a function of $k$**:

[image]

You will tabulate a number of points $(k_i,x_i)$ once for all (say $10$ of them). Then when you need to solve for a certain $k$, look for the bracketing interval $(k_i,k_{i+1})$ and use the Lagrangian interpolation with, say, the four points $i-1,i,i+1,i+2$. For efficient implementation, use the [Neville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm) computation scheme.

A more thorough analysis is required to determine the density of the points required to achieve the desired accuracy, based on the remainder formula of Lagrange. Different combinations are possible, from a single higher order polynomial to several lower order local ones, and different placement of the points.

You can even precompute the polynomial coefficients for all intervals, so that given a $k$ you find $x$ with, say, $5$ multiplies and $3$ additions, which is possible, though tedious, by hand.

For the sake of illustration, here is a plot of the third degree polynomial interpolating the whole positive range from points $x=0,x=0.5,x=0.75,x=1$.

**Cubic interpolator $x = -0.0318k^3 + 0.0501k^2 + 0.4705k$**:

[image]

Comment: I totally agree with what you wrote. However, I see a small problem : $x(k)$ reaches a maximum value of $1$ at $k=1+\frac \pi 2$ and decreases to $0$ at $k=\pi$. The funny thing is that, as a test, the value $1+\frac \pi 2 <k=3<\pi$ was proposed ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I mentioned that there is another branch (related to the $\arcsin$), which I didn't want to address. Cheers.

Comment: I am sorry ! I did not "see" this good point (may I confess that I am almost blind ?). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use the calculator, the following method(Iteration method) very easy.

if we select $k=3$
$$\sin(3-x)\rightarrow x$$
the arrow means the cell store in calculator.

the following result when the initial $x=1$
$$0.90929742$$
$$0.86786576$$
$$0.84654367$$
and then continue

Answer (score 0):

In case you couldn't find a calculator, or do computations but got a thread and ruler/compass/...

- Draw a circle of radius 1, and measure an arc of $k$ degrees for ACB.
- Take a portion of a long thread (Orange in figure) that is marked. and measure some length $2x$, and bisect it to $CD$ and $DE$.
- Place the first half $DC$ along the arc.
- If the endpoint $E$ of the other half touches $E'$ (so that $DE$ is perpendicular to AB) we are done. Otherwise, increment length equally at both ends $C, E$.

[image]

*We are approaching point $E'$ as the length $x$ increases from both ends, thus $D$, moving along the circle, is kept *invariant as the bisection point*.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x - \sin(k-x)$. It is trivial that there is no zero when $|x| > 1$. We also know that $f(0) = -\sin(k) \ne 0$.

The problem with the Newton's method is that it will fail when $f'(x) = 0$.

Let $x-k=y$, $g(y) = f(y+k) = y + k + sin(y)$. Let's also constrain $k \in [-pi/2, pi/2]$.

Using the Taylor's series for $sin(y)$, $g(y) \approx y + k + y - y^3/6$.

Thus:
$$
g(y) = 0 \\
k + 2y - y^3/6 = 0 \\
y^3/6 - 2y - k = 0 \\
y^3 - 12y - 6k = 0
$$

I used the WolframAlpha to help solving this polinomial.

All three solutions can be seen [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%20-%2012x%20-%206*k%20%3D%200)

You can notice that only one solution is between $[-1, 1]$. [Take a look at this solution.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%282%20%281-i%20sqrt%283%29%29%29%2F%283%20k%2Bsqrt%28-64%2B9%20k%5E2%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29-1%2F2%20%281%2Bi%20sqrt%283%29%29%20%283%20k%2Bsqrt%28-64%2B9%20k%5E2%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_*Math-)

Let $w = 3k + \sqrt{-64+9 k^2} = 3k + i\sqrt{64-9 k^2}$. But, as $|w| = 8$, it can be rewritten as $w = 8 cis(\alpha)$, $\alpha = arg(w) = acos(3k/8)$.

Let $z = \sqrt[3]{w} = 2cis(\alpha/3)$.

Thus, our root is $y = \frac{2i(\sqrt{3}+i)}{z} - \frac{(1+i\sqrt{3})z}{2}$. Using the polar form for complex numbers, $y = 2cis\left(\frac{2pi}{3}-\frac{\alpha}{3}\right) - 2cis\left( \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\alpha}{3} \right)$.

But we already know that $y$ is a real number. So, let's get only the real part.

$$
y = 2cis\left(\frac{2pi}{3}-\frac{\alpha}{3}\right) - 2cis\left( \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\alpha}{3} \right) \\
y = 2\cos\left(\frac{2pi}{3}-\frac{\alpha}{3}\right) - 2\cos\left( \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\alpha}{3} \right) \\
y = -4 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{6} - \frac{\alpha}{3} \right) \\
y = -4 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{6} - \frac{cos^{-1}(3k/8)}{3} \right)
$$

Finally, $x = k -4 \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{6} - \frac{cos^{-1}(3k/8)}{3} \right)$, if $k \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

Let's check: $$
k=\pi/4, x = 0.38744, f(x)=-0.00009688 \\
k=\pi/3, x = 0.51073, f(x)=-0.00037297
$$

Notice that any value of $k$ can be mapped in the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$.

We still have to solve for $k \in [-pi, -pi/2)$ and $k \in (pi/2, \pi]$. But, notice that, for k in these intervals, we can just map $k$ to the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ and invert the sign of $sin(x-k)$.